# How do you make Trimetric Cubes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, isometric

I saw this really cool cube graphic:

[image]

I know you can create isometric cubes in illustrator & photoshop, but how do you create this cube (not isometric angles), with directly editable side colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Illustrator, use the **Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel** option

Create a square

[image]

Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel

[image]

Object > Expand Appearance

[image]

Now you have an easily editable cube.

Add inner strokes, to achieve that look

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I have a question: how do you find out the exact angles to use to get the example's angle?  I will mark as the answer soon ;)

Comment: @Alex the angles are up to you, I was just showing you the method.  Everything else is your call.  Play around until it looks right.

Comment: Alright!  It's just there's one problem:  in your clone of it, the inner stroke does not cause the right perspective.  See the smaller squares, the only one that looks right the right side's one.

Comment: @Alex because my cube is not perfectly symmetrical. I just did this as a quick reference to show you _how_ to do it.  I wasn't showing you _exactly_ what to do.  You still need to figure the rest out on your own